# Opening up port 8080 in CentOS

Tags: centos, port

I'm new to opening up ports in CentOS. I need to open up tcp port 8080 and have installed/ran nmap to find it is not open already. I've been reading about the iptables command, I have v1.3.5 installed but I really don't know where to start with it regarding opening up this port.

I'd appreciate a code sample or at least a link to a guide to opening this port using iptables (or any other good method.)

Thank you.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

I always like to add a comment and limit scope in my firewall rules.

If I was opening up tcp port 8080 from everywhere (no scope limiting needed) for Tomcat I would run the following command

```
iptables -A INPUT -m state --state NEW -m tcp -p tcp --dport 8080 -j ACCEPT -m comment --comment "Tomcat Server port"
```

Then make sure to save your running iptables config so that it goes into effect after the next restart

```
service iptables save
```

Note: you'll need to have the comment module installed for that part to work, probably a good chance that it is if you are running Centos 5 or 6

P.S.

If you want to limit scope you can use the -s flag. Here is an example on how to limit traffic to 8080 from the 192.168.1 subnet

```
iptables -A INPUT -m state --state NEW -m tcp -p tcp --dport 8080 -s 192.168.1.0/24 -j ACCEPT -m comment --comment "Tomcat Server port"
```

Comment: I performed the first statement you listed, saved it, and restarted the server. I can't seem to see the 8080 opened using nmap?

Comment: In case anbody has experienced that the port didn't open after giving this command, you may have a target REJECT already existing in the INPUT chain and your new rule only added after that (I had this problem) which never reaches. So you have to insert your rule before the REJECT. First use `iptables -L -n --line-numbers` to display all rules with numbers and then use `iptables -I INPUT <n>` instead of `iptables -A INPUT` in the command in the answer (where <n> was the number of the REJECT target). This will insert your new rule above the REJECT and it should work.

Comment: @prajeesh what is the command to move the order of the REJECT rule down? Do i just delete it then re append it below?

Comment: @Nassign Yep, delete that REJECT then insert it at the position you want

Answer (score 51):

For CentOS 7:

```
firewall-cmd --permanent --add-port=8080/tcp
firewall-cmd --reload
```

See [the documentation for FirewallD](https://fedoraproject.org/wiki/FirewallD#Permanent_zone_handling).

Comment: Seems FirewallD should be running for these commands, otherwise its not working.

Comment: @unibasil If the firewall daemon is not running, then you don't have a firewall at all, so you don't need to "open up" any ports at all, they're already open.

Comment: how to close it again?

Comment: @kiltek `--remove-port` does the opposite of `--add-port`.