# Not able to access Tomcat webserver from another machine in the LAN

Tags: tomcat, centos7, firewalld

I have setup the basic tomcat website (tomcat 8.0.3) on a server inside my company LAN. From my work computer if I try to access the website by typing it into google chrome it is not working.

The IP of the computer on which the Tomcat server is running is `192.1xx.132.125:8080`. The IP of my work computer is `192.1xx.129.75`.

I am able to ping my work PC to the server. If I type `http://192.1xx.132.125:8080` on google chrome browser on my PC I get the following error.

[image: Google Chrome error!]

Can someone please point out why this is happening? Also My webserver is headless.I can access the webpage on that server using `curl`. Since this is a non-conventional port number do I need to update the IP tables on my server?

I have run this command

```
 sudo iptables -A INPUT -m state --state NEW -m tcp -p tcp --dport 8080 -j ACCEPT -m comment --comment "Tomcat Server port"
```

as mentioned in `http://serverfault.com/questions/341804/opening-up-port-8080-in-centos`

Comment: @FedericoSierra - How can I check that?

Comment: Try wtih `iptables -L`

Comment: @FedericoSierra - Please see the update to the question above.

Comment: Ok, Try to test enable port 8080 `iptables -A INPUT -p tcp –dport 8080 -m state –state NEW -j ACCEPT`, also check if tomcat is listening with `netstat -ant | grep 8080`

Comment: @FedericoSierra - no output for iptables command.But tomcat is listening on 8080

Comment: Seems you have Centos 7 try `firewall-cmd --zone=public --add-port=8080/tcp --permanent` and `firewall-cmd --reload`

Comment: @FedericoSierra - Very Impressive.It worked.Thanks :) Do I have to save that so it is not lost across reboots

Comment: You do not need anything more, the rules were applied permanently (`--permanent`).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For Centos 7 you can enable the port `8080` with the following commands:

```
firewall-cmd --zone=public --add-port=8080/tcp --permanent 
firewall-cmd --reload
```

Comment: what command I need to fire for Windows?

Comment: @GreenROBO I'm not an expert in windows, take a look at https://www.howtogeek.com/school/windows-network-security/lesson4/

Comment: Yeah! I got it. Thank You. :)